# Умножение двоичных чисел Машиной Тьюринга

Tags: алгоритм

Всем привет!
Семестр уже подошёл к концу, но я хотел бы попросить помощи в одной задаче, чтобы лучше понять Машины Тьюринга и алгоритмы.
**Задача**

> Построить ТМ для умножения двух двочиных чисел.

Мои решения (чтобы не нагромождать - опишу лишь в общих чертах):

**Решение №1.**

- Переводим оба числа в унарную систему счисления.
- Копируем второе числе ровно столько раз, сколько единиц в первом числе (всё пишем в одну строку, после каждого копирования просто удаляем одну единицу из первого числа и делаем пока первое число не кончится).
- Переводим итоговую строку в двоичную систему счисления

**Решение №2.**
Используем многоленточную ТМ с неограниченным числом лент.

- Читаем первое число с конца, если 1 - копируем второе число на первую свободную ленту, если 0 - не копируем (альтернатива - пишем нули).
- Читаем второе число - то же самое, но со сдвигом на один разряд, а в конце дописываем 0.
- Когда числе 1 прочитали до конца - суммируем все получившиеся числа и итоговая сумма и есть результат умножения.

**Искомое решение**
В принципе я бы мог успокоиться, т.к. получил зачёт, но я пытаюсь построить одноленточную ТМ, которая бы делал всё то же самое без перевода в унарную систему счисления и обратно. К сожалению, все мои попытки получаются репрезентацией ТМ из второго решения, но чуть сложнее. А я ищу что-то элегантное и простое. Ни у кого нет идеи, как можно построить ТМ, чтобы не было громоздко и работало на одной ленте? Неужели нет простого алгоритма?

Comment: Решение 1 - одноленточное, верно? Тогда *я пытаюсь построить одноленточную ТМ* - она уже есть в решении 1? Или решение 1 считается двухленточным?

Comment: @nick_n_a имел ввиду, без перевода в унарную систему счисления и обратно. 
Спасибо за уточнение, впишу в условие.